# SQL Trigger Compilation Error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am new to SQL Triggers.

The below trigger gives me a error saying that

> Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>
> Error: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

```
create or replace trigger HIST
  after update of DATE ON EPISODE  
  for each row

begin

INSERT INTO HIST SELECT * FROM INSERTED;

end HIST;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Apart from the invalid reference to INSERTED (as pointed out by @Parado), the column name DATE is invalid since DATE is a keyword in SQL. If you really have a colum named DATE (I sincerely hope you don't!), you'll have to enclose it in double quotes.

Comment: ohh I didnt know inserted doesnt work on oracle.. thank you so much .. and yeah I dont habe date as my column name :D Thanks guyyss

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `INSERTED` table on Oracle DB.
You should use `new` values insetad as below

```
INSERT INTO HIST (col1,col2)
VALUES (:new.col1,:new.col2)
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_tr.htm) you can find more information about triggers.

Comment: That should probably be :new.col1, :new.col2